# How to delete rows from UITableView without animation in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have an accordion type of `UITableView` that works but I just need to adjust the animation slightly. When a row is clicked a method is called that deletes the rows that are showing then adds the new rows to show. I don't want to animate the rows being deleted. I only want to animate the part when the rows are being added. I can use `[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];` to turn off the animation all together but I just want to turn it off for the deleting part.

```
    [self.unitListTableView beginUpdates];
    [self.unitListTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:delete withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    [self.unitListTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:added  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [self.unitListTableView endUpdates];
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: did you try using `nil` instead of `UITableViewRowAnimationTop`?

Comment: yep. those withRowAnimation's do nothing. ive also tried UITableViewRowAnimationNone. it still just runs the animation where it adds rows one by one.

Comment: Not on a Mac right now but I think if you call `reloadData` you won't see any animation.

Comment: HAS, if you put it as the answer ill tick it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `reloadData` on your table view and it updates without any animation.